# The difference between a sentence starting with 'to' + verb and starting with a gerund

Tags: grammar

What is the difference between the following two sentences?

> To study English is hard.
>
> Studying English is hard.

Comment: Everything depends on the predicate. Many predicates allow both gerund and infinitive subject complements, but others vary. Every predicate is, in the end, different in terms of what constellation of constructions and collocations it is part of.

Answer (score 0):

They mean much the same thing, although there can be a nuanced difference. Consider these sentences:

**To climb Mount Everest requires training and dedication.

Climbing Mount Everest requires training and dedication.**

Since "climbing" brings in the idea of the climb-in-progress, it might be thought to be less suitable than the infinitive form to the notion of *prerequisites*.

Comment: They mean much the same thing in the case of _hard_ and _require_, but not for every predicate.